# Linker error despite including the files

Tags: visual-studio, linker

I am having a linker error LNK 2001 unresolved external symbol.My point is I do have the respective include directory added under Project Settings->C/C++->General ->Additional Include .I see that this include directory does have the header file which contains the function which is causing the error.
I also add all the lib folders under linker options->general->additional lib dependencies.
What could be going wrong? How can I trace what file is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need more than just the library path, you need to specify the libraries explicitly.  i.e `something.lib` 
(under *Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies*  in VS2005)

Answer (score 0):

Linker errors have nothing to do with include files. You get compiler errors from missing include files/directories. The linker needs the actual definitions aka code to work its magic and create your binary file (exe/dll/static library etc...).

Are you linking to the library of which you are `#include`ing the headers from?